# php replace substring with regex

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

Ok, i know there are trillions of similar questions, but i'm finding it really hard to achieve this.
I have some strings of this formats:

```
$x = '<iframe src="[File:19]"></iframe>';
$y = '<img src=[File:2212] />';
$z = '<source src="[File:42]" />';
```

I'm trying to get the id given after the `File:` and also replace the whole `[File:xxx]` with another string. I'm trying like the following, but it seems i can't fully understand the usage of preg_replace.

```
$file = ('<iframe src="[File:134]"></frame>');
$rex = "/^.*(\[File:[0-9]{1,}\])/i" ;
if ( preg_match($rex, $file, $match) ) {
    echo 'OK';
}
$file = preg_replace ($rex, "http://lala.com/la.pdf", $file);
echo "<br>".htmlentities($file)."<br>";
```

Could you please give me some hints on how i can do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use `preg_match_all` and delete `^.*`.. (should work) **But** actually you should use [PHP DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

`preg_match('/\[File:(\d+)\]/i', $str, $match)`

$match[0] will have the whole string, $match[1] will have just the number.
After the regex match, you can use `str_replace` to remove $match[0] from the string.

Example:

```
$x = '<iframe src="[File:19]"></iframe>';
preg_match('/\[File:(\d+)\]/i', $x, $match);
var_dump($match);
```

Gives:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "[File:19]"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "19"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change these 2 lines

```
$rex = "/^.*(\[File:[0-9]{1,}\])/i" ;

$file = preg_replace ($rex, "http://lala.com/la.pdf", $file);
```

to:

```
$rex = "/^(.*)\[File:[0-9]{1,}\]/i" ;

$file = preg_replace ($rex, "$1http://lala.com/la.pdf", $file);
```

This will capture what is before `[File...]` into group 1, then in the replace part, add this group (i.e. `$1`) in front of the replace string.

It can be rewritten as:

```
$rex = "/\[File:\d+\]/i" ;

$file = preg_replace ($rex, "http://lala.com/la.pdf", $file);
```

Comment: Is it just me, or is `/^(.*)\[File` not only a very useless bit, but also very bad for performance? `/^.*\[File/` comes down to `/\[File`, does it not? If you don't capture it in the regex, you don't have to replace it, right?

Comment: @BerryLangerak: Yes, you're right, I've just taken the OP's regex with minimum changes.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
<?php
$formats[] = '<iframe src="[File:19]"></iframe>';
$formats[] = '<img src=[File:2212] />';
$formats[] = '<source src="[File:42]" />';


foreach( $formats as $format ) {

    $regex = '~\[File:(\d+)\]~';

    $replace = function( $matches ) {
        return 'http://lala.com/la.pdf?id=' . $matches[1];
    };

    var_dump( preg_replace_callback( $regex, $replace, $format ) );
}
```

I've created a lambda for the replacement, because I have a feeling you want to use the id after `File:` instead of just discarding that. Have fun with it. If you have any questions, do tell.

Comment: You don't need to capture the whole expression in parens.  By default the whole matched region is stored in $matches[0].